How to group_by() by two variables in a dplyr call?
I am getting the mean by week (wk), however, wk 21 doesn't have data all so I would like
to get the mean by 'month' instead. How do I switch group_by(wk) to group_by(month) in the
same dplyr call? The final result for wk 21 should be 5.8.
library(dplyr)
fish <- structure(list(wk = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22), month = c(5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6), pd = c(6, 
4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 
4, 5, NA, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")

fish %>% group_by(wk) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(pd, na.rm=T))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     wk   Mean
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1    20   5   
2    21 NaN   
3    22   6.25


You can't have 2 different groupings active, but you could do something like this:
fish |> 
  group_by(month) |>
  mutate(month_mean = mean(pd, na.rm = TRUE)) |>
  group_by(wk) |>
  summarise(Mean = coalesce(mean(pd, na.rm=T), first(month_mean)))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#      wk  Mean
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    20  5   
# 2    21  5.8
# 3    22  6.25


They are both good answers, thank you. I have a question for  @Gregor Thomas. Would your approach work if other weeks are completely emplty as well? For example, in this case wk 21 is completely empty but would this work is wk 38 and wk 49 are empty as well? I am asking because you are estimating the month_mean across two months here but if I want to apply your suggestion to other weeks the month_mean will be estimated across multiple months?

It would be ideal to estimate the monthly_mean within each month where the wk with no values resides.

My month_mean is estimated by month, not across different months. If you want to group over multiple months, then you should define a new variable (maybe quarter?) and calculate that mean. And for simplicity I used first() to use the monthly mean that corresponds to the first day of the missing week, but you could, of course, do other things instead, e.g., Mean = coalesce(mean(pd, na.rm = TRUE), mean(month_mean)) which would average the month means weighted by the days in each month.

If you want more details on a special case, I would suggest asking a new question with data to illustrate and your desired result clearly explained.

I expected to get the mean month 5 only because is where wk 21 is which it should be 5.8 but instead I got a mean of 5.8333 because it seems like month_mean is getting the mean of months 5 and 6 together.

Ah, I forgot the month grouping. Added now, and you will get the means by month.

Week 22 includes more than one month. How would you want to deal with cases where a given week straddles two months and has all missing data in one or both months?
If you're willing to work with a list of data frames, you could run the summary hierarchically down the grouping levels, which would get around the multiple membership issue for weeks. For example:
library(tidyverse)

fish <- structure(list(wk = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22), month = c(5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6), pd = c(6, 
4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 
4, 5, NA, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")

grps = quos(month, wk) 

seq_along(grps) %>% 
  map(~fish %>% 
      group_by(!!!grps[1:.x]) %>% 
      summarise(Mean = mean(pd, na.rm=TRUE))
  ) 
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'month'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   month  Mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     5   5.8
#> 2     6   6  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   month [2]
#>   month    wk   Mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     5    20   5   
#> 2     5    21 NaN   
#> 3     5    22   6.33
#> 4     6    22   6

# As a function
cum_groups = function(data, mean.var, ...) {
  
  groups = enquos(...)
  
  seq_along(groups) %>% 
    map(~data %>% 
          group_by(!!!groups[1:.x]) %>% 
          summarise(N=n(),
                    {{mean.var}} := mean({{mean.var}}, na.rm=TRUE))
    ) 
}

cum_groups(fish, pd, month, wk)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'month'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   month     N    pd
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     5    19   5.8
#> 2     6     2   6  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   month [2]
#>   month    wk     N     pd
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     5    20     7   5   
#> 2     5    21     7 NaN   
#> 3     5    22     5   6.33
#> 4     6    22     2   6

cum_groups(mtcars, mpg, cyl, am, vs)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl', 'am'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>     cyl     N   mpg
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     4    11  26.7
#> 2     6     7  19.7
#> 3     8    14  15.1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl    am     N   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     4     0     3  22.9
#> 2     4     1     8  28.1
#> 3     6     0     4  19.1
#> 4     6     1     3  20.6
#> 5     8     0    12  15.0
#> 6     8     1     2  15.4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#> # Groups:   cyl, am [6]
#>     cyl    am    vs     N   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     4     0     1     3  22.9
#> 2     4     1     0     1  26  
#> 3     4     1     1     7  28.4
#> 4     6     0     1     4  19.1
#> 5     6     1     0     3  20.6
#> 6     8     0     0    12  15.0
#> 7     8     1     0     2  15.4

Created on 2024-10-14 with reprex v2.1.1
